# How can I plot a tree on R with several parents for a node?

Tags: r, graph, tree

I'm trying to plot some tree-like graph on R

[This is what I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlkiu.png)

Here goes my code (I'm using library "data.tree"):

```
library(data.tree)

a <- Node$new("a")
b <- Node$new("b")
c <- Node$new("c")
d <- Node$new("d")

a$AddChildNode(b)
a$AddChildNode(c)

b$AddChildNode(d)
c$AddChildNode(d)

plot(a)
```

[But this is what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4wzH.png)

Comment: Something similar to this is achievable but it's not converging at `d` : `library(data.tree);
a <- Node$new("a");
b <- a$AddChild("b");
d <- b$AddChild("d");
c <- a$AddChild("c");
d <- c$AddChild("d");
plot(a)`.

Comment: The tree (by definition) has unique parents! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)